# latexdiff doi entries in bibtex / bbl file?

Tags: bibtex, latexdiff, bbl

I'm trying to do tracked changes for my references in latex using `latexdiff` and `bibtex`.

What I am doing is running `latexdiff` on the original and updated `*.bbl` files and while this works well for things like title, journal, authors, etc. it fails to work for things like DOI that are enclosed in tags.

Is there any way to mark a change in a doi entry of a `*.bbl` file?

At the moment `latexdiff` will create something like this in the `*.bbl` file:-

```
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \doi{https://doi.org/10.1038/nature14283}%%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \doi{10.1038/nature14283}\DIFaddend
```

but it only compiles as the updated version without any markup, this still happens if I make the `*.bbl` file readonly to stop `pdflatex` making any changes to the `*.bbl`, where I want the additions and deletions shown as markup

Comment: I don't have time to test, but experiment with either `--append-textcmd=doi` or `--append-safecmd=doi` options

Comment: @frederik Thanks `--append-safecmd=doi` worked perfectly.  If you want to add it as an answer I will upvote and mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latexdiff does not know about \doi and to be on the safe side will not include unknown commands in the argument of a mark-up command (as this can lead to actual error messages for many commands). But you can tell it about commands that will not interfere with the markup style and are safe to be used in the argument of the markup command by using this option:

`--append-safecmd=doi`